# Android Login Activity Running Slow

Tags: android, performance

I'm making an app with Login. Everything else on the App runs at normal speed with any device, but my Login activity runs reaaaally slow in some devices when using the EditText and for showing the android Keyboard. On my cellphone is a Samsung Young 2 (Really cheap and slow Cellphone) it goes really fast, but on the Huaweii Y6 of one of my friends it runs extremely slow (Cheap Cellphone but not so slow as mine), and on the Huaweii P8 it also runs slow. Here's the XML code (the java code doesn't interfere as I deleted trying to see if that was the case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.uta2.rallyuninorte.Login">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo_rali"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <!-- User Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Usuario" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Activity Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/activity_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Actividad"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Entrar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:onClick="open_menu"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Solution:**

As they wrote, the problem was the logo_rali image, wich size was just 46kb, but the image size was 1600x1200. I changed to 280x190 and solved my problem

Comment: Can't comment on why it's slow but is there a reason you're using a `CoordinatorLayout` as your top layout here?

Comment: It came as default when i created a new basic activity, but I also changed to relative and linear and it goes slow too

Comment: I think the problem is in your `@drawable/logo_rali`, check if it's heavy or change it and try to be more sure !

Comment: I also agree with the comment above. I had an activity with a drawable jgp inside that was slowing the whole process massively. I solved it with parsing it down to a smaller png file. which made a giant difference.

Comment: Indeed that was the case. Thanks a lot man